# Convert unicode characters to html special characters

Tags: php, unicode

I have unicode characters embedded into strings like this:

```
64\u00be w &times; 19\u00bd d &times; 16\u00be h in (164 &times; 50 &times; 43 cm)
```

Now I want to convert them like this:

```
64¾ w × 19½ d × 16¾ h in 164 × 50 × 43 cm
```

So far I tried this:

```
$desc = '64\u00be w &times; 19\u00bd d &times; 16\u00be h in (164 &times; 50 &times; 43 cm)';
echo mb_convert_encoding($desc, 'ASCII', 'HTML-ENTITIES')
echo html_entity_decode( mb_convert_encoding ( $desc, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ASCII' )
```

But both does not convert the unicode characters, what I am missing here?

Comment: Where did the string with \u00be notation come from? Can you get the changed so that it is less programming-language-focused and more data-transfer focused? (It is a valid JSON document containing an HTML string, though.) Or, perhaps it's just a debugging dump rather than an actual value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple hack like this (it should not have any performance issues):

```
$a = '64\u00be w &times; 19\u00bd d &times; 16\u00be h in (164 &times; 50 &times; 43 cm)';
$html = json_decode('"' . $a . '"');

echo $html;
```

Comment: @unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: I found new lines causing the error of parsing, now it works.